# On geometric interpretation of commutative rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Recently I am reading *Basic Notions of Algebra* by Shafarevich, and have some questions about it.
My question is about the interpretation of commutative ring as a geometric object.
More specifically, book claims,

1. For any point $x_0$ on set $X$, one can interpret it as ring homomorphism such as, $x_0: F(X) \rightarrow K$, where $F(X)$ is the functions ring on $X$ and $K$ is a field that corresponds to range of $F(X)$. More precisely, constructed as follow,
   $$
   \begin{array}{ccc}
   x_0: F(X) & {\longrightarrow} & K \\
   {\in} & & \in \\
   f & \longmapsto & f(x_0)
   \end{array}
   $$
2. Because any point on $X$ has the corresponding homomorphism on field, it can be related to [maximal ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_ideal) which is isomorphic to kernel of homomorphism.
   If unfamiliar with this check [Wikipedia:Ring homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism).
3. Alternatively, one can take any ring and interpret it as geometric object by relating maximal ideals with points on geometric object.
4. For example of this idea, book took $\mathbb{Z}$ and claimed that it should be interpreted as function ring on set of prime numbers. Because maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as (p) and this will corresponds to points on base space of function ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

I have 2 questions about it.

1. I do agree that one can relate points on $X$ to ring homomorphism, but relating it to maximal ideal is where I am confused. is it obvious that mapping between each point on X to the maximal ideal is injective?
2. Interpreting $\mathbb{Z}$ as function ring on Set of prime number (I'll denote it as $P$) is also confusing one.

- If corresponding maximal ideals are $(p)$, doesn't that implies range field of $\mathbb{Z}$ is [$\mathbb{F}_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) and so , it is different on each point in P? if so, can this be called "function" on P?
- Also, assuming one can call it as function, function ring made by these kinds of functions P $\rightarrow \bigoplus_p\mathbb{F}_p$ will not be a [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(ring_theory)) ring. but on other hand, $\mathbb{Z}$ is domain. So, these two can't be isomorphic to each other. Is $\mathbb{Z}$ actually able to interpreted as function ring on $P$?

I hope my question makes sense.
thanks.

Comment: If your question is about how to view elements of a ring as functions on its spectrum, then both Eisenbud/Harris (the Geometry of Schemes) and Vakil (his famous notes, the Rising Sea, I believe the name is) have nice and detailed discussions and exercises about this.

Comment: thanks, that's very very helpful!! I'll check it. Meanwhile, I have a very little background on geometric algebra so it may take me amount of time. 
is there any intuitive explanation of why $Z$ can be veiwed as function on prime numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This is adapted directly from Eisenbud/Harris: Take any prime $p \in \mathbf{Z}$. For any other prime $q$, which is naturally a point* $x \in \operatorname{spec}(\mathbf{Z})$, $p$ defines a function, call it also $p$, by sending it to its residue value in $\mathbf{Z}/q$. So the map here is the natural quotient map $\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{Z}/q$, and the value of $p$ on $x$ is the class of $p$ in $\mathbf{Z}/q$, suggestively denoted $p(x)$.

They then ask you to compute the value of $15$ (as a function) on at the points $(7)$ and $(5)$ of $\operatorname{spec}(\mathbf{Z})$, which could be a good exercise if you are completely new to the subject. For more details I urge you to read the text. It is very forgiving for beginners.

*Or rather the ideal it generates, but let us not be precious.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I do understand the idea, but still have questions. 
in this formulation what will be the range of $\mathbb{Z}$ ? isn't it different for every point on spec($\mathbb{Z}$ ) (question 1)? if so, resulting function ring may not be a domain, where $\mathbb{Z}$  is domain so these two cannot be isomorphic to each other, so is $\mathbb{Z}$  really can be a function on spec($\mathbb{Z}$ ) (question 2)?

Comment: what I'm imaging as function $\mathbb{Z}$ is something like this, which takes differnt field as range of function on each point.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{F_2}&&&&&\mathbb{F_3}&&&&\mathbb{F_5}&&&&&\mathbb{F_7}&&&&&& \\
\\
&&&&&&&&&\uparrow\mathbb{Z}&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\end{array}\\
\rule{11cm}{0.4pt} spec(\mathbb{Z})\\
\begin{array}{ccc}
(2)&&&&&(3)&&&&(5)&&&&&(7)&&&&&&\\
\end{array}
$$
 if we interprate it as a function $\mathbb{Z}: spec(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \bigoplus_p\mathbb{F}_p$, is this really a domain?

Comment: for example, if we take two functions like (1,0,0,...) and (0,1,0,...) from this ring, where each column represent value of function on each point on $spec(\mathbb{Z})$, product these function will be zero even those are non zero functions on $spec(\mathbb{Z})$.
on the other hand, $\mathbb{Z}$ as ring always satisfies ab = 0  $\Rightarrow$ a=0 or b=0. so, these two cant be isomorphic to each other as ring. so my question is what is this function ring and how can one think of it as same as ring $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: while writing, I realized one can't take functions like (0,1,0,0,..) on this ring. 
but still one can always take function like (1,2,0,3,...) which takes 0 on only finitely many places or (0,0,0,0,..) which takes 0 everywhere. 
for example 6 will be (0,0,1,6,6,...).
if we consider product of functions as (2*3)(3*5)(5*7)... = 6*15*35*... , this will still be zero.

Comment: Note that $\mathbf{Z}$ is itself not a function, but its elements can be viewed as "functions" on the prime numbers. Note also that the targets of these functions ("functions") vary from point to point, and there are non-zero functions whose value is $0$ on all of its source.

Comment: thanks. yes, but my point is if there are nonzero functions whose value is 0 in all its source, than the ring made by these functions is not a domain right? but on other hand $\mathbb{Z}$ is domain. so, aren't these two rings different?
sorry for repeated questions... and thank you for kind replies. I love this example and really want to understand it.

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph Why are you taking prime $p$? Any arbitrary integer works, right?